# mapping objects to JSON vs object relational mapping

Tags: json, orm, relational-database

I know very little about ORM and JSON and i would like to ask if its possible to
say that mapping objects into JSON is easier than mapping object into relational database and why or why not.

I wrote this in one of my school work: 
*The advantage of document oriented databases is JSON. You can easily convert objects of most programming languages into it and put them directly to the database without difficult mapping process between relational table and object like in relational databases.*

Dont know where i read this but i probbably didnt interpret it correctly. Thanks in advance